# Programmatically Accessing CQ5 Content using the JCR

Tags: java, aem, jcr, sling

I would like to access the content programmatically, I tried the following:

```
private Session getSession(String user, String passwort) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4503/crx/server");
            JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4503/crx/server");
            session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials(user, passwort.toCharArray()));
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return session;
    }
```

I get the following exception when I call the `getRepository` method:

```
 javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings:
        org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: http://localhost:4503/crx/server
    The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
    Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.
```

I have the version cq5.4. Any idea?

P.S: I tried to Access publish and author instance and got the same exception.

Comment: What happens when you access the repository in your browser? & also, do you get anything printed to your `error.log`?

Comment: @anotherdave: When I access http://localhost:4503/crx/server with the browswer I get the following: CRX 2.2.0.71

Available Workspace Resources:
•crx.default

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by CRX 2.2.0.71

Comment: Seems like it would be fine. Do your JCR logs give any indication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need and don't want to call `JcrUtils.getRepository` in a Sling/CQ app, you should rather access the SlingRepository OSGi service that CQ provides.

The simplest is to use an `@Reference` annotation in an OSGi declarative services `@Component` - there are multiple examples of this in the Apache Sling codebase, the http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks sample is a good starting point for that.

If your code executes as part of request processing, you don't need to create a Session yourself, you can get it by calling `request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class)` where `request` is the `SlingHttpServletRequest` that you get in a Sling servlet.

Comment: `SlingHttpServletRequest ` extends `HttpServletRequest `, this provides method `request.getSession()`. Is there a difference between `request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class)` and `request.getSession()`?

Comment: `HttpServlet.getSession` returns an `HTTPSession`, which in general you don't want to use in Sling applications as it makes things stateful. `request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class)` provides the JCR `Session` that you need to access the JCR content repository.

Answer (score 1):

here's a barebones service to get an admin session:

```
package your.package;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.*;

import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
import javax.jcr.Session;

@Component(immediate=true, enabled=true)
@Service
public class YourServiceForRepository {
    @Reference
    protected SlingRepository repository;

    protected Session session;

    @Activate
    protected void activate() throws Exception {
        session = repository.loginAdministrative(null);
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate() throws Exception {
        session.logout();
        session = null;
    }
}
```

you can also modify this to return a session based on credentials. but it's unclear what context you're trying to get a session from, so i can't give any pointers on how to structure your service.

Answer (score 0):

Holding onto a JCR reference such as a session or a node as part of bundle activation is a  bad idea since the session or the node can become invalid over time - I've had to debug and fix this problem in the past. Instead, you should use the @Reference annotation and adaptTo method described above or loginAdministrative() when it's absolutely required for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Using an OSGi bundle is fine if you want to interact with a JCR from an OSGi service. However - you can still interact with it from an external Java App. Purhaps you want to write a Java tool to get user within an AEM JCR and dump them to a spreadsheet.

In your above example - http://localhost:4503/crx/server may not have been the proper URL. You may be http://localhost:4502/crx/server. BUt this works - see: http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.ca/2012/03/programmatically-accessing-day-cq.html

And once done with the session- close it: 
session.save(); 
session.logout();